# cannot load editor in mozilla thimble

Tags: editor, mozilla

I am deploying [Mozilla Thimble](https://github.com/mozilla/thimble.mozilla.org) locally.I have followed the [ReadMe.md](https://github.com/mozilla/thimble.mozilla.org/blob/master/README.md).All the servers are running fine.but at the end when i tried to visit the **http://localhost:3500/en-GB**.the output can be seen below.

[image]

I have googled around but couldn't find any solution.

Any suggestion????

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is a recent bug and was reported on the Thimble project Github page [here](https://github.com/mozilla/thimble.mozilla.org/issues/1601).

They are still triaging and figuring out the problem, so keep an eye on that bug for a solution.

Comment: I have read into this issue too.but no lead.is there anyone who have deployed thimble l.ocally

Comment: One of the latest comments mentions a [PR](https://github.com/mozilla/thimble.mozilla.org/pull/1605) that fixes the particular issue you mentioned. I guess it will land in a day or so.